# Executing USSD via AT command from Huawei modem does not produce the expected result

Tags: gsm, at-command, ussd

**Summary:** Using a program I have written in javascript (node.js), sending USSD command for a specific MNO (Mobile Network Operator) service does not return me the expected output. To my surprise, commands returns 'OK' and output is readable, but it is not what I asked for. Using the same program, if I send MNO's other commands, like check available balance I get the expected output.

**Details:** 
I run the following commands (both from putty and my program) to send USSD code:

```
AT+CUSD=1,"GSM ENCODED STRING",15
```

And I get back something as:

```
+CUSD: 0,"GSM ENCODED STRING",15
```

We have written an npm module for encoding and decoding of GSM 7-bit type of USSD ([ussd-pdu-text-converter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ussd-pdu-text-converter)) and using the same, we can encode our USSD command and decode the message returned back from MNO to human-readable format.

Running USSD works fine for the operations that MNO provides from its side, like checking available balance. We send the USSD, and get back the response containing the information we needed. No matter how many times we run the command, we get the same output.

The problem raises when we want to use a third party service that the MNO provides (something like Caller Ring Back Tone or CRBT). When I use putty and our program to run the USSD command for such a service, every time I get a different result. Something that I do not expect, or I did not ask for. For example:

- You do not have enugh balance to use this service
- You are not registered for this service
- Your balance is AFN 3000.
- Your balance is AFN 40.
- etc.

This gets more interesting to know when we run the command from a mobile phone, we get back the response as we expect! No matter how many times we run it. We get the unique response we expect.

**What I have checked already:** 
I have tried the followings with no result:

```
- AT+CSCS="IRA"
- AT+CSCS="UCS2"
- AT+CSCS="GSM"
- AT+CUSD=1,"GSM ENCODED COMMAND"
- AT+CUSD=1,"GSM ENCODED COMMAND",15
- AT+CUSD=1,"GSM ENCODED COMMAND",32
```

**My questions:**

What could be the case/algorithm that the mobile phone(s) consider that we do not do in our program, hence we get the strange outputs? Any suggestions how to solve it?

**Update:** I could do a work around, and broke the ussd command into a two step USSD command, of course MNO has a support for that, but still I have not been able to find out why that command itself does not work.

Comment: For sending USSD commands you shouldn't have to encode as they are numeric commands anyhow. The USSD responses are also normally decided by the modem and displayed in ascii (IRA) format so you only need to decide if your MNO's 3rd party responds in UC2. Would be really useful to see some code and also the USSD command codes you are sending. Might be able to give you some better insights then.